# JSON with multiple Objects to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, nsdictionary

I have a little Problem with JSON to NSDictionary, and hope someone can help me:

From an URL-Request i get JSON Objects like this:

```
{
    page = 1;
    results = (
        {
            adult = 0;
            "vote_average" = 5;
            "vote_count" = 100;
        },
        {
            adult = 0;
            "vote_average" = 3;
            "vote_count" = 10;
        }, 
        {
            adult = 0;
            "vote_average" = 1;
            "vote_count" = 300;
        },
    );
    "total_pages" = 1;
    "total_results" = 3;
}
```

Now I need to parse this JSON Objects into NSDictionary.
My problem is that there are more (this time 3) JSON-Objects and each Object has same keys. 
I think i need to create a NSDictionary for each JSON Object, do I? ..is there a simple way to do this? Or is there another "usual way" to handle such a situation?

Thanks fore Help!

Comment: It's already parsed into an NSDictionary.  Which contains an NSArray named "results".  Which contains 3 NSDictionary objects.  No further parsing needed.  What you need to do is to simply "peel the onion" of objects you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to create all objects seperately , NSJSONSerialization can do the job for you.The changing number of items comes inside the array so The count of objects in the array will increase,that is all

Use

```
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

data is the json string converted to NSData

Edit : Well the structure the json to dictionary and array is prettys straight forward   `{` indicate it id a dictionary and `(` or `[` indicate it is an array,and if it is in nested condition yeah the dictionary is also in the same way

So in your case You have to populte the array and get the object in array index and it will have a dictionary and there you can achieve a single value

So in your case

```
    NSArray *results=[jsonResultDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSDictionary *dict=[results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"vote_average"]);
```

Comment: Yes, I used this code:

NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

But now all Objects are in the NSDictionary. How can I get the Value of a key from one of these objects?

If I simply try to get "vote_average" like this:

test = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"vote_average"];

the value of test is "(null)"

Comment: Alternatively: `NSArray *results = jsonResultDictionary[@"objects"]; NSDictionary *dict = results[0]; NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"vote_average"]);`

Comment: @user2355509: You're conflating two different things. The outermost dictionary contains (among other things) an array which contains the three “objects”, and those “objects” are themselves dictionaries. The outer dictionary doesn't have a `vote_average` key; the three “object” dictionaries do. You need to get the array from the dictionary and then walk through (or store) the array.

Answer (score 0):

That's a dictionary and the key of results has a value that is an array if dictionaries. NSJSONSerialization can deal with that.